# Which small displays have been confirmed to work?

Tags: display, hdmi, screen

Which small (7-10") displays have been confirmed to work with the Raspberry Pi?

Also, what should I consider when looking to buy one of these displays or trying to integrate one with my Raspberry Pi?

Comment: Welcome to `raspberrypi` Eax. I have suggested an edit which tries to make the question look less like a purchase recommendation question, which have a limited shelf life, to get at the heart of your question. Feel free to accept the edit or use my suggestion to see how you might improve your question yourself.

Comment: Not trying to be patronising, but any screen that has a HDMI or Composite (RCA) connection should work.

Comment: This question is very similar to: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/936/what-qualities-should-i-look-for-in-a-small-7-or-10-monitor

Comment: The wiki hardware DB could probably use a screen section and refactoring the adapters into it. http://elinux.org/RPi_VerifiedPeripherals

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apart from the usual DVI/HDMI and composite connector monitors it is possible to use the DSI connector to connect to a raw LCD screen.

At the moment there is no confirmed list of monitors I have found but it really depends on which distribution you intend to use, for instance I ran Debian Squeeze and it didn't recognise my BENQ G2222HDL 22" 1080p LED PC monitor correctly and used some messed up resolution like 1900 * 982 or whatever whilst XBMC detected it correctly straight away.

Anyway, there is more information on your screen options here: http://elinux.org/RPi_Screens

Answer (score 1):

I've seen [several accounts](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JWCzwU9_g3E) of people using extremely small LCD screens intended for automobiles via the DSI connector. Like EdChum, I haven't found a full list, though.

I hope you find more information. I'm looking for this as well.

Comment: In that video, the screen is connected using the composite not the DSI interface. As far as I understood, DSI seems to be problematic because the GPU code is closed source.

Answer (score 1):

dealextreme cheap 17,00€ car rear view display works with raspi ;-) Dx.com order code is 49796. its 12v device and you can use it as 3,5" screen, the text needs some altering to get working.