# Will a Raspberry Pi work with a non-official Pi screen?

Tags: pi-3, touchscreen

I'm using the official Raspberry Pi 7" touchscreen, but since it's rather expensive, I'm wondering what to look for (and look out for) in a touchscreen for the Pi 3 (or Raspberry Pis in general).

Comment: Welcome! Purchasing recommendations themselves are off-topic here, but there are a few past questions which might be helpful, such as [What qualities should I look for in a small, 7“ or 10” monitor?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/936/58316) and [How can I determine if a given touchscreen is compatible?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/28/58316). These might be a little outdated, but you can also find other comparisons online such as [this one](http://wonderfulengineering.com/10-best-raspberry-pi-touchscreens/) which may be better suited to helping you in your search.

Comment: Rather than close your question, I've modified it along the lines Aurora0001 mentions.  The ban on shopping requests is partially to avoid becoming a free advertising site, and partially to avoid "I was too lazy to search online myself..."; hopefully that criteria seems straightforward and reasonable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply search for keyword ' 7" LCD Rapberry Pi ' in ebay, you will get a list of them. Contact sellers before purchase, make sure they have instruction to make it work on the latest RPi firmware, or else you may end up with a product that supports earlier version only.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the raspberry pi will work with any screen or display unit as long as it has an HDMI port. suppose if you computer pc display has DVI-D display, You can buy a converter of HDMI to DVI-D.